# Call a function from preg_replace in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

**The String**

```
$string = '<img width="624" height="36" id="Picture_x0020_3" src="cid:image002.png@01D12C22.B28006A0" alt="cid:image003.png@01CFBD71.8CD95080">';
```

**The Function**

```
final_content = preg_replace('~src=["]([^"]+)["]~e', "'src=\"data/'.convert_url('$1') . '\"'", $string);
function convert_url($url)
{
    if (preg_match("#^cid?:#", $url)) {
        $url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    }
    $url2 = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "@"));
    $url2 = 'data/143-'.$url2;
    return basename($url2);
}
```

I want to replace the image source from the above mentioned string.

> actual pattern :src="cid:image002.png@01D12C22.B28006A0"
>
> replacement : src="data/image002.png"

The script is working fine in normal PHP code but since I am using CodeIgnitor the calling of the function is not possible in traditional way.

After analyzing a lot of answers found that use preg_replace_callback instead.

**Using preg_replace_callback() in CodeIgnitor:**

```
$final_content = preg_replace_callback(
            '~src=["]([^"]+)["]~',
            array($this, 'convert_url'),
            $string);
```

**The Function for CodeIgnitor:**

```
function convert_url($matches)
    {
        if (preg_match("#^cid?:#", $matches[1])) {
            $url = parse_url($matches[1], PHP_URL_PATH);
        }
        $url2 = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "@"));
        $url3 = 'src=\"data/'.$url2.'\"';
        return basename($url3);
    }
```

The Function consist of replace the pattern(i.e. 'cid:' with 'data/143-') as well as trimming the content (i.e. after @).

---

**Found the Solution:**

Found the solution by changing the preg_replace by preg_replace_callback and used array to call the function.

Also made further changes in the convert_url() since the preg_match("#^cid?:#", $url) was not working in the function.

/e modifier needed to be replaced /i since it was deprecated.

Replace preg_replace with preg_replace_callback

```
 $final_content = preg_replace_callback(
            '~src=["]([^"]+)["]~i',
            array($this, 'convert_url'),
            $string2);
```

Remove preg_replace from the function and used a different technique to extract the string.

```
function convert_url($matches)
    {
        $url = $matches[0];
        $url2 = $this->get_string_between($url,'src="cid:','@');
        $urls = "'$GLOBALS[id]-$url2'";
        $url4 = 'onclick="open_img('.$urls.')" src="data/'.$GLOBALS['id'].'-'.$url2.'"';    
        return strtolower($url4);
    }
    
    function get_string_between($string,$start,$end){
        $string = " ".$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0) return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you write this code? in view page or controller? if you write this code into controller then need to call a function like this
    $this->convert_url('$1').

Comment: I'm writing this code in the controller. And yes I have tried using $this->convert_url('$1') in the preg_replace(). It still shows convert_url() as undefined function.